# Firemonkey: TWebBrowser not shown when using it in form with BorderStyle None

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8, delphi-10-seattle

I am developing a Firemonkey application in Delphi XE8 and found the following situation:

I need to show a small webpage in a small form with only a TWebBrowser control with Align:=Client and Form BorderStyle = None but for some reason in Windows the Form appears gray and the TWebBrowser is not shown as you can see in the pictures. In Mac OS work as expected.

Also it happens if I disable one of the BorderIcons like Minimize, Maximize or SystemMenu. I have tried with Delphi 10 and the same issue. I have tried with the trial version of TMS WebBrowser for Firemonkey (TMSFMXWebBrowser) and the same issue.

Form with TWebBrowser and FormStyle = Single in Win32
[image]

Form with TWebBrowser and FormStyle = None  in Win32
[image]

Form with TWebBrowser and FormStyle = Single and Maximize Button = False  in Win32
[image]

Form with TWebBrowser and FormStyle = Single in Mac OS
[image]

Does someone know the reason and how I can fix this? I really would like to show the webpage in a form without any border/icon like in Mac OS.

Comment: That is very odd. I think you should report this to Embarcadero as bug as it happens even if you place a TWebBrowser on some other container component like TPanel and then change the form style to borderless.

Answer (score 0):

new this component at run-time, not add it in your interface when design
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tCRU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Problem still exists after almost 7 years.
The workarond is to put content in the temporary file, then Navigate to it.
But if we set form's Transparency = true this workaround doesn't work too.